# Spring 16 Developer Console - menus inoperative - Uncaught TypeError: b is not a function

Tags: developer-console, debugging

Between 2016-01-19 and today, 2016-01-22, my Developer Console stopped working in Spring 16, cs21.

**Symptoms:**

1. All menu items do not drop down to a list of actions (instead, empty dropdown)
2. No tabs are refreshed with their prior state (logs, test results)
3. Browser console shows `Uncaught TypeError: b is not a function` in `ApexIDEPanels` (see screen shot below)

To paraphrase Monty Python:

> 'E's not pinin'! 'E's passed on! This developer console is no more! He
>   has ceased to be! 'E's expired and gone to meet 'is maker! 'E's a
>   stiff! Bereft of life, 'e rests in peace!

**Analysis:**

1. Occurs on all browsers - Chrome-Firefox-Safari-Opera
2. Others in my org do not experience this issue
3. Is not browser-related because I can log into my org from others' computers who have a working/functional DC, yet when I use their computers with my login ID, I get the same failure. Additionally, I installed Opera just today to rule out cookies or any browser state.  Browser Refresh Hard does not help. DC works fine for me in a different Spring 16 org on the same computer (cs11)

This leads me to conclude that the current state of **my logs, query results and testresults** causes DC to blow up whereas other user's logs/testresults/queryresults don't have such pernicious effect.

I can't delete the `ApexLog`s from the DC as the 'Use Tooling API' checkbox doesn't display.  Using Workbench to delete `ApexLog` and `ApexTestResult` has yet to bear fruit.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, spring time!  By doing nothing between Friday and Monday, the problem went away.  No uncaught exceptions in the browser console.  I can only conclude that either

1. The DC state ages away and hence the problem self-corrects. None of my log tabs were shown when I opened the DC on Monday.
2. SFDC fixed something in Spring 16 over the weekend

> Update - problem recurred (late March 2016), some additional solutions:

1. [SFDC Help article](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000205964&language=en_US) on correcting invalid workspace.
2. I had multiple open DC windows (all expired, for three orgs, all in Chrome, one with a pending Test Suite dialog confirmation). I closed all of them and problem went away.

Comment: I don't think this is fixed. I'm experiencing it right now on CS21.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that - you get the same Console error that I included in the OP?  The only workaround I could come up with was to create a new user and continue development that way

Comment: @frontendloader - see update